# Backendless.com Business Logic - Making an HTTP Request to Google Places API

Tags: google-api, google-places-api, backendless

I am using Backendless.com as a BAAS for my application. I have some custom logic running on their servers which need to make an HTTP request to the Google Places API.

I'm trying to generate an API key for the Backendless.com server to run this request but i'm not sure what API key I need to generate. The Google developer console gives me 4 options. Server Key, Browser Key, Android Key, & iOS Key.

Server key seems to be the one I want to use... but I need to provide it with some IP addresses... I don't know where or how to find those! The console states that they are optional, but it seems insecure to not add the server IP address. What are the risks? Where can I find Backendless.com app server IP's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Server key is what you want. Restricting access is a good additional security step to take, it is not however required. They basically make it so that if someone manages to steal your API Key, they can't use it from IPs that are not whitelisted. You will have to ask backendless.com if they have a finite list of IPs they can gurentee your requests will come from.